# How to write footnote citation in beamer in one line?

Tags: latex, beamer

I am using `beamer` `latex` and I need to give reference in the `footnote`. My reference is about 2 lines. but when I write the following code it writes it in more lines!!!

```
\begin{frame}
 \frametitle{R: Literature Review}
 \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
  Huo et al. \footfullcite{Huo, et al. ``Computerized ...''}
\end{frame}
```

the output is like this:

```
Guo,
et al. ”Prediction of clinical phenotypes in invasive breast carcinomas from the integration of radiomics and genomics data.”
no. 4 (2015): 041007-041007..
```

Do you know how I can do it in just 2 lines?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Sorry the references in my question are not the same.. but my question is right.

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem might be, that latex has problems to hyphenate the title of the article. An easy workaround is to let latex do the work and use bibtex or biblatex.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

% only for this example, otherwise in .bib file
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Huo2002,
    author = {Zhimin Huo and Maryellen L. Giger and Olufunmilayo I. Olopade and Dulcy E. Wolverton and Barbara L. Weber and Charles E. Metz and Weiming Zhong and Shelly A. Cummings},
    title = {Computerized Analysis of Digitized Mammograms of BRCA1 and BRCA2 Gene Mutation Carriers},
    journal = {Radiology},
    volume = {225},
    number = {2},
    pages = {519-526},
    year = {2002},
    doi = {10.1148/radiol.2252010845},
    note ={PMID: 12409590},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
    \frametitle{R: Literature Review}
    \setbeamerfont{footnote}{size=\tiny}
    Huo et al. \footfullcite{Huo2002}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

A little trick: do not use comma after 'Guo' (or 'Huo')!

```
\footfullcite{Huo et al. ``Computerized ...''}
```